# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined (php + pdo)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, exception

I have this query that without the inner join it works:

```php
$sql = 'SELECT prodotti.nome, prodotti.prezzo, prodotti.sku, prodotti.produttore, fornitori.nome
                FROM prodotti INNER JOIN fornitori
                ON prodotti.fornitori_id = fornitori.id
                WHERE prodotti.id = :prodotti.id';
         
$id = 1; // for example
// $this->db-> (is connection)
        
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':prodotti.id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$prodlist[$id] = $results;
         
var_dump($prodlist);
```

If I run it I get this error:

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE [HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in ........

It seems that the error lies is in the `WHERE` and in a particular way, reading online, I discovered that it could be a problem to do this: `WHERE prodotti.id = prodotti.id;`

suggest to do for example: `WHERE prodotti.id =: id ';` and then in the `bindparam` the same thing `$stmt->bindParam(': id', $ id, PDO :: PARAM_INT);`
in fact, doing so works halfway, in the sense that it gives me back the data called the first 'products' table ignoring the second 'suppliers'.

Can anyone tell me where am I wrong? Thanks

if I run this query on the SQL section of DB it works.

```
SELECT prodotti.nome, prodotti.prezzo, prodotti.sku, prodotti.produttore, fornitori.nome 
FROM prodotti INNER JOIN fornitori 
ON prodotti.fornitori_id = fornitori.id 
WHERE prodotti.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

as some users have pointed out to me elsewhere, and in fact it partially solves the problem, the point cannot be used in the binding, as reported in the guide at this link:
https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

"Note that PDO supports positional (?) and named (:email) placeholders, the latter always begins from a colon and can be written using letters, digits and underscores only. Also note that no quotes have to be ever used around placeholders."

now it works correctly! Thanks